# same web User Interface for computer and mobile?

Tags: css, layout, html, slice

My question is about resolutions and user interface of web sites. I am developing a free web site for a non profit organisation for having experience and I have not worked with mobile apps/ web sites. Will thankful if you please can help me.

Can you please guide me as per best practices UI for computer browser and for mobile are same or two different UI are developed ?

I am also confused what is standard resolution for a web site and how to manage resolutions on different screen sizes (of course cannot develop for different screen sizes).

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique in use right now is responsive design.  That is, your design and layout of the page will adapt for the resolution and orientation of the device it is being displayed on, without a need to change anything.

The easiest way to get started with this is CSS media queries.  Check out this article for more general information:  http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/